# Помогите удалить строку

Tags: java, строки

На просторах интернета нашёл такой код, но он почему-то не пашет:

```
  public static void clearScreen() {
        System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");
        System.out.flush();
  }
```

Суть его в том чтобы он удалял прошлые строки

Answer (score 2):

Для работы этой команды у терминала должна быть поддержка последовательностей ANSI.

Консоль eclipse и cmd такой поддержки не имеет, в отличие от терминала линукса.

Comment: И что делать???

Comment: @FussionBart Технически ваш код отлично работает, но не везде. Для эклипса могу посоветовать плагин "ANSI Escape in console", либо придётся запускать код на линуксе.

Comment: А для idea ничего не посоветуешь?

Comment: @FussionBart Нет, но я уверен что в гугле полно различных плагинов и для неё.

Comment: Еще такой вопрос эта команда удаляет все строки до неё, или последнию, мне нужна конкретно последняя

Comment: @FussionBart Да, `[2J` отчищает консоль, `[H` перемещает курсор в начало.